# Substituir uma tag para receber uma imagem sem mudar o resultado

Tags: php, css

Estou criando uma pagina dinâmica com MVC. Em um determinado ponto eu usei o seguinte código para preencher uma DIV com uma imagem do meu BD:

```php
 <div class="col mx-3 my-3 doub1 effect" style="background-image: url('<?php echo URL . 'assets/imagens/artigo/' . $imag; ?>'); width: 450px; height: 350px;">
```

e aproveitei para colocar um H2 que vai pegar o campo nome e um

que pega a descricão.

```php
<h2><?php echo $nome; ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $descri; ?></p>
```

Pois bem... a div é preenchida completamente pela imagem e o Título e a descrição ficam por cima. Eu queria muito aplicar algum efeito interessante sobre essa imagem e encontrei na NET um exemplo em que ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem ela irá deslizar para a direita e mostrará a legenda com o título e a descrição. Vejam:

```js
<ul class="demo-1 effect">
<li>
<h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
</li>
<li><img class="top" src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>
```

O grande problema é que eu não usei a tag `img` no meu exemplo, como vocês viram eu coloquei a imagem no background-image da DIV. Agora não estou conseguindo aplicar o efeito na minha página porque não sei como adaptar esse código aí com o meu.
Como eu poderia usar esse exemplo no meu código ou mudar o meu código para usar esse ai sem causar danos aos resultados que já tenho ?

Answer (score 0):

você atualmente somente informou o seu código HTML com PHP, acredito eu até onde chega meus conhecimentos, que é necessário para você realizar esse efeito de mostrar legenda e deslizar imagem, uma combinação de CSS com JavaScript, eu ainda arriscaria que seu eu fosse realizar esse código eu usaria JQuery.

Para facilitar sua vida e busca por resposta, recomendo você pesquisar sobre a propriedade hover em CSS, ele executa mudanças no elemento que no caso seria a sua imagem quando você passar o mouse por cima, e você poderia usar o hide ou show do JavaScript para exibir ou ocultar tambem, usando o evento onmousehover do JavaScript.

Exemplo de Animação com JavaScript onmousehover: [Click Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)

Exemplo de Animação com Css: [Click Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_fade1)

Veja a combinação:
Veja no CodePen: [Código 100% Funcional](https://codepen.io/jhefferson-matheus/pen/poLmqbp)

```js
document.getElementById("hideShow").style.display = 'none';

function show(x) {
document.getElementById("hideShow").style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(x) {
document.getElementById("hideShow").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
.btn {
  background-color: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-left: -40px
}

.btn:hover {margin-left: 10%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Deslizar e Mostrar Legenda - CSS + JavaScript</h2>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <p id="hideShow">Legenda</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide(this)" class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo, acredito que não fui claro na minha pergunta. Na verdade, eu consigo fazer com CSS mas usando listas e a tag <img>. No caso a imagem seria um item <li> da lista. Porem, no meu código eu coloco a imagem como Background-image da DIV e para isso indico o caminho através da instrução url: '(aqui dentro coloco o endereço da imagem e o código PHP) ' . A minha dúvida é exatamente como criar o mesmo efeito que está sendo criado usando uma lista <ul> e itens <li> no meu exemplo com div.

Comment: Assim, eu uso background-image de uma div que eu chamei de bolt1. No exemplo que peguei na Net o cara usa uma <ul> que ele chamou de effect e dentro dela como item <li> um elemento <img>. No CSS ele aplica o efeito chamando .effect img { + o efeito. Ai reside a duvida, como eu vou aplicar o efeito no meu caso e a imagem está como background da div ? Entendeu ????

Comment: você pode aplicar o efeito diretamente na div em que a imagem está como Background, os efeitos os quais você aplica a div irá se replicar na imagem, se assim for melhor mande o código de referência.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo publicar uma resposta nem comentário contendo o código

Comment: Teria como eu te mandar o código de outra forma ?

Comment: você pode editar a pergunta